# Cmake unable to generate debug info for RelWthDebugInfo configuration for MSVC target

Tags: cmake

I need to ENABLE debug info generation for Release build in Cmake for MSVC.

I'm using RelWthDebugInfo config. But i need to remove /DNDEBUG option and replace it with /DDEBUG:FULL

How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

3 hours of struggling and I found solution:

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "/DDEBUG:FULL" CACHE FORCE)
```